# Redirect from one PWA to another PWA shows the address bar

Tags: mobile, progressive-web-apps

So, here's the problem: I have two sites with PWA configured and both are working just fine, Site-A and Site-B.

And what I would like to do is, when I'm visiting Site-A via the standalone app, to redirect it to Site-B.

Although the redirection works without any problem, Site-B is loading with the address bar visible. Is there any way to prevent this and show Site-B full screen too?

Thank you everyone!

Kind regards,
Stratos

Answer (score 1):

Declarative Link Capturing was dropped in favour of the [Launch Handler API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/launch-handler/) and shipped in Chrome 110.

Answer (score 0):

In Feb 2021, there's no way to do this, but it's coming.

Chrome and Edge are working on something called [Declarative Link Capturing](https://github.com/WICG/sw-launch/blob/master/declarative_link_capturing.md) that will allow you to do this, but it's still in design/development. You can follow along on the Chromium tracking bug [#1163398](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1163398)